# What should I use for IOT Things?

Tags: arduino-ide, bluetooth, wifi

I am very much interested in using the Blynk. Well I like it because of its feature. I want to control or read my sensors or something like that remotely. So Blynk says you need something like esp8266 or BLE stuff or something similar. I came across NodeMCU and Ethernet shield. I want to buy something that is efficient for reading my sensors. Is there anything similar that is similar to NodeMCU and is Arduino IDE compatible.

Comment: NodeMCU can be programmed from the Arduino IDE. You just need to instal the board files.

Comment: Is there any thing similar to that ?

Comment: Why would you want anything else? It seems that you want something, but have no idea what? The NodeMCU is a good choice for general IO over wifi.

Comment: You know I wanted to know what are the other choices

Comment: the d1mini is like the nodemcu only smaller and no extra power pins. esp32s are under $10 now/

Comment: D1 is not compatible with Blynk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming Esp8266/NodeMCU does not have enough IO for your application? (It combines Wifi with Arduino for little cost and is compatible with the Arduino IDE development tool)

Aruino have a different solution called the [Arduino Yun](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardYun). The problem with the Yun might be that it doesn't have very much memory and is based on the Atmel 328 processor (which has some IO but maybe not enough for you).

An alternative I have heard good reports about is the [Dragino Yun Shield](http://www.dragino.com/products/yunshield/item/86-yun-shield.html). That is a shield that provides powerful networking, sits on any Arduino board and works the same as an Arduino Yun. Therefore a Yun Shield sitting on an [Arduino Mega2560](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega2560) would give a lot of memory and a good supply of IO.

Comment: But the price tag is quite high

Comment: Yep that's why I said the NodeMCU is cheap. The Yun has a preconfigured linux/linnino server so in theory its networking is much more powerful than the Esp8266